# Can I fork libstdc++ without disclaiming copyright for the modifications I make?

Tags: gpl-3, copyright

**NOTICE:** Not A duplicate of [Am I allowed to add additional copyright on modified code that originally the FSF released under GPLv3](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/10773/am-i-allowed-to-add-additional-copyright-on-modified-code-that-originally-the-fs):
The previous question answered if I'm allowed to copyright modifications to software published by the FSF at all. The current question tries to find out if the FSF applies the same rules regarding copyright to forking as they do to contributing.

I've been reading the [GNU FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#AssignCopyright) and found the following:

> **Why does the FSF require that contributors to FSF-copyrighted programs assign copyright to the FSF? If I hold copyright on a GPLed
> program, should I do this, too? If so, how? (#AssignCopyright)**
>
> Our lawyers have told us that to be in the best position to enforce
> the GPL in court against violators, we should keep the copyright
> status of the program as simple as possible. We do this by asking each
> contributor to either assign the copyright on contributions to the
> FSF, or disclaim copyright on contributions.
>
> We also ask individual contributors to get copyright disclaimers from
> their employers (if any) so that we can be sure those employers won't
> claim to own the contributions.
>
> Of course, if all the contributors put their code in the public
> domain, there is no copyright with which to enforce the GPL. So we
> encourage people to assign copyright on large code contributions, and
> only put small changes in the public domain.
>
> If you want to make an effort to enforce the GPL on your program, it
> is probably a good idea for you to follow a similar policy. Please
> contact licensing@gnu.org if you want more information.

From my understanding I must disclaim copyright or assign it to the FSF if I'm contributing to FSF-copyrighted programs. Does the same apply if I fork the project in order to modify it and port it to another compiler?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I allowed to add additional copyright on modified code that originally the FSF released under GPLv3](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/10773/am-i-allowed-to-add-additional-copyright-on-modified-code-that-originally-the-fs)

Comment: really... the same question again, 12 hours later?

Comment: @planetmaker I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.  As you said previously "Yes, you may do so, provided you abide by the license of the repository you forked" however this doesn't answer my concern and I still cant find if the same rules apply to contributing and forking, its not explained in the FAQ and it wasn't answered previously because last question I didn't mention forking.

Comment: Though my answer does explicitly.

Comment: @planetmaker You mentioned in the previous post "The first statement is a requirement the FSF has when you like to contribute directly to one of their projects." This answers regarding contribution only. However, it doesn't mention what are the requirements for forking (if any) and I didn't find any section regarding forking in the FAQ. Moreover, you said "provided you abide by the license of the repository you forked" and that's what I want to find out exactly - what does the license say about forking ?

Comment: as I told you in the answer there, the quoted FAQ part here has no bearing and relation to and on what *you* are allowed to do with the code at all as as it only deals with the FSF procedures and requirements for accepting patches.

Comment: I understand this "FSF procedures and requirements for accepting patches", but there is literally 0 information regarding **forking**, what I don't understand is if the same applies to **forking** this is the question I'm asking. In addition I 100% understand that the quote I added from the FSF has nothing to do with forking it was there as a reference to show that I know what must be done if I contribute and thus your answer doesn't apply to this specific question.

Comment: Note that the FSF's policy ranks third in line, after copyright law and the GPL text itself.

Comment: @globalturist: Your previous question is also about forking, because it says "My intentions are to post it on github as a standalone project." That's forking, so this question is indeed a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: @Kevin making a new project on github doesn't mean I'm forking it at all... I want to fork only to give FSF more credit and to show where the original code came form that's all. Also, how is it the same question if I clearly show what I'm asking 2 different things or maybe I don't know what my questions are about and you know better perhaps ? And "That's forking" to my knowledge to fork you need to click the fork icon and I'm sure there is more than 1 way to start a standalone project

Comment: Also, @Kevin I'd like to avoid talking about purely opinion based matters because its not what the site was created for. If you think its a duplicate just don't answer, there is no need to tell people you understand better than them what they are asking for when there is a valid reason in the NOTE section for both questions existing.

Comment: This is in fact a duplicate of https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/10773/am-i-allowed-to-add-additional-copyright-on-modified-code-that-originally-the-fs where it has already been thoroughly answered.   *This* posting seems to exist only because the asker is confused about the meaning of the word "fork" - however as "fork" has *no legal meaning* it's entirely irrelevant if the word applies to the proposed actions or not.  @planetmaker already explained that the proposed actions are permitted, and did so in a way not dependent on the word "fork".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not a legal concern, but one of project policy. What this FAQ item says is essentially: if you submit contributions to the GNU project, they will not use them unless you first assign copyright to the FSF.

You are free to make modifications to GNU code and retain copyright on your modifications, but do not expect them to be accepted back into mainline GNU code. (This may not be something you want to do anyway.)

Comment: From what I understand I can retain copyright for my modifications if I fork libstdc++ without the intention to ever contribute/make pull requests. However, if I contribute only then should I assign copyright to the FSF did I understand it correctly ?

Comment: @globalturist Yes, in other words, the GCC project is not interested in having to handle distributing a codebase with lots and lots of copyright owners (because that makes any license change a nightmare). If you're fine with having to handle these concerns for your tree yourself, you can just go ahead. The FSF just tells you they're not interested in incorporating your modifications if they come with strings attached (in the form of a requirement to ask your permission for any further license change or enforcement).

Comment: @TooTea https://gcc.gnu.org/contribute.html recently changed, so that GCC no longer insists on a copyright assignment for contributions.